# RedShift: rounding numeric after case when construction

Tags: amazon-redshift

I try to use this transformation

```
    CASE
        WHEN s.files_duration != '' THEN s.files_duration
        ELSE 0.0 
    END :: NUMERIC AS files_duration_2
```

for RedShift.

I'm waiting for decimal in this field like: 2.52 etc. But value is rounding to 3 etc. Why?

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By casting to a numeric without scale is basically defining it as an integer, so 3.  From RS docs "The default scale, if not specified, is 0."

There are a number of questions raised by this SQL fragment (like is s.files_duration a string or a numeric type?) but the cast to NUMERIC(18,0) seems to be the root of the issue.  Try NUMERIC(12,2) - or whatever precision and scale that make sense for your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!